# setInterval does not keeep going

Tags: javascript

### When *ctdwnDecCall()* is called, it displays 8 but only once and it should every second, this script is at the head of the page

```
    var ctdwnDecInt;
    function ctdwnDecCall()
        {
            ctdwnDecInt=setInterval(ctdwnDec(),1000);
        }
        function ctdwnDec()
        {
            document.write("8");
            
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use `document.write` in an interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably write something like this ([JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nugox/2/edit))

```
var Timer = function Timer(elem, seconds) {
  elem = elem;
  seconds = seconds || 10;

  var interval = null;

  function render() {
    elem.innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(update, 1000);
    }
  }

  function update() {
    seconds = seconds - 1;
    render();

    if (seconds === 0) {
      stop();
    }
  }

  function stop() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  this.start = start;
  this.stop = stop;
}
```

Usage becomes easy mode now

**HTML**

Here we setup a couple timers and use the class `timer` (you can pick whatever you want)

```
<span class="timer"></span>
<span class="timer"></span>
<span class="timer"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

Find all timers by class `timer` (or whatever you pick) and initialize a new `Timer` object for each of them. In this example, we set each timer to have an `8`-second countdown.

```
var timers = document.getElementsByClassName("timer");

for (var i=0, len=timers.length; i<len; i++) {
  var t = new Timer(timers[i], 8);
  t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `ctdwnDec` function, not setting in up on an interval. You need to remove the `()`:

```
var ctdwnDecInt;
function ctdwnDecCall() {
    ctdwnDecInt=setInterval(ctdwnDec ,1000);
              // no parens in there ^
}
function ctdwnDec() {
    document.write("8");
}
```

Comment: Calling *document.write* after the load event means clearing the entire document, which is likely unexpected by the OP…

Comment: @RobG What do you mean it clears the entire document?

Comment: @matthewpavkov—that it removes **everything** in the document, the entire head and body, scripts, everything.